# Can you order your monsters to commit suicide?

Tags: firetop-mountain

Can you order to a monster that you control (Goblin, Ogre, Troll or Giant - Elementals are another thing) to attack himself?
Will they kill themselves in that case?

*EDIT: this trick may be of some use if your opponent is about to take over your monster with a Charm Monster and you can not protect it with a counter Spell or similar*

Comment: ...Have you tried it?

Comment: I could try, but then I would risk losing a duel... this game doesn't forgive this kind of things...

Comment: I know you could do it on [Raven Black's](http://games.ravenblack.net/) implementation, at least.

Comment: WOW! I didn't know that there is another version in the net!!!...

Comment: @Yaztromo : Be carefull, there are some light differences in the rules between those two flavors of the same game (www and PBem)

Comment: @Yaztromo ... and that is one of the reasons I prefer PBem. This auto-kill means that Charm Monster is almost always failing. No Fun.

Comment: @Pierre: really good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not ask this to anyone. It's a personal decision. ;-)