# What are the differences between Firetop Mountain and Warlocks?

Tags: firetop-mountain

As part of [this previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64209/can-you-order-your-monsters-to-commit-suicide) I learned that [Warlocks](http://games.ravenblack.net/) is another version of [Firetop Mountain](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/index.html), but it's not perfectly the same.
The most evident difference is that Firetop Mountain is a play-by-email game, while Warlocks is played on line, through an interface screen.
There are also some small differences in the games rules and mechanics.

I had a deeper look at the detail and I found that Warlock have some alternative rule being playtested (like having the gesture DSF causing maladroitness instead of confusion or having paralyzed hands taking different positions), but that's just an option.

Another difference that I spotted is the fact that, in Warlocks, Paralysis is "as strong as" the other enchantments and, for example, can be used to "counter" an Amnesia, while in Firetop Mountain Paralysis is "weaker" that the other enchantments and, for example, would allow Amnesia to take place instead.

I spotted the fact that the four-gesture version of Lightning Bolt is renamed "Clap of Lightning", but that has no impact whatsoever on game mechanics.

From [a comment made by Pierre to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64209/can-you-order-your-monsters-to-commit-suicide) (thank you, Pierre) I also gauged that summoned monsters can be ordered to suicide by their controllers, making this way Charm Monster spell much less interesting and useful for the game (when an opponent is about to charme your monster you order it to commit suicide so you won't see it fighting against you...).

Is there any other difference between the two games?

EDIT: I found other differences:

-in Firetop Mountain you can't have more than 15 life points (if, for example, you cast a cure light wounds at yourself and you have 15 life points, you don't increase your points bewond 15, while in warlocks you can have more than 15 life points by using a cure wounds or similar.

-in Warlocks, even if you are subject of a Fear spell you still can stab (what's the sense of this?), while in Firetop Mountain you can't (and it makes a lot of sense in my opinion).

-In Firetop Mountain you can play 2 vs 2, with two (or three, etc.) mages controlled by you vs two (or three, etc.) mages controlled by your opponent (it's a nice variation of the game!), but in Warlocks this option is not allowed.

Comment: Trivia: These are both re-implementations (or altered copies) of the original freely-distributed [Spellcast](http://www.eblong.com/zarf/spellcast.html) for unix-like systems, which is itself based on a physical game invented by Richard Bartle. Comparing Firetop Mountain and Warlocks to their parent game might be interesting (e.g., Fear won't let you stab in Spellcast, so Warlocks is being deviant there).